# Ustream API - Javascript seek in iframe player

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, embed

I'm tring to seek the Ustream video player to go to 60sec for exple

But It's not working.
**What's wrong with my code?**

```
<iframe id="UstreamIframe" src="//ustream.tv/embed/recorded/24364591" style="border: 0 none transparent; margin-top:1px;" frameborder="no" width="720" height="437"></iframe>

<a id="link1" href="javascript:;">0001</a>
<a id="link2" href="javascript:;">0001</a>
<a id="link3" href="javascript:;">0001</a>

<script src="http://static.ustream.tv/js/libs/ustream-embedapi.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var viewer = UstreamEmbed("UstreamFrame");

    $('#link1').click(function(){ viewer.callMethod('seek', 60);})
    $('#link2').click(function(){ viewer.callMethod('seek', 90);})
    $('#link3').click(function(){ viewer.callMethod('seek', 120);})
  });
</script>
```

This is how they do it: http://ustream.github.io/api-docs/embed-api/index.html

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's your issue? I don't see a question.

Comment: True sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like that:

**Please make my code easier, shortener and cleaner if possible.**

```
<iframe src="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/recorded/24364591" id="UstreamFrame" width="640" height="392" style="border: 0 transparent none;"></iframe>
<br>
<a id="link1" href="javascript:;"><span>0sec</span></a><br>
<a id="link2" href="javascript:;"><span>60sec</span></a><br>
<a id="link3" href="javascript:;"><span>120sec</span></a><br>

<script src="http://static.ustream.tv/js/libs/ustream-embedapi.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewer = UstreamEmbed("UstreamFrame");

        $('#link1').click(function(){
            viewer.callMethod('seek', 0);
        });

        $('#link2').click(function(){
            viewer.callMethod('seek', 60);
        });

        $('#link3').click(function(){
            viewer.callMethod('seek', 120);
        });
    });
    </script>
```